# Issue with help utility in Factor programming language

Tags: stack, listener, factor-lang

I am using the Factor programming language for Mac. From the Listener (Factor's interactive GUI) I read that I can get the help with the following command, but when I type

```
\ at help
```

To get help about the "at" term, I get the following error message:

[image]

Comment: I don't have a Mac, so I can't test this. Does it happen when you click the help button in the listener or F1?  Maybe you should let the devs know, at the github page or the mailing list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example should work and show the documentation window. 
From the picture it appears you are using a very old version as the latest versions using a completely different icon. Suggest you download a recent version and try again.